# Как передать в NpgsqlCommand параметр из C#?

Tags: c#, postgresql, plpgsql

Как можно передать в скрипт передать внутрь `DO $$ ... END $$` значение параметра `@_data`:

```
--здесь @_data виден:
insert into table(id, mnemo, data)
select 1, _mnemo, @_data;

DO $$
DECLARE
    _mnemo  varchar(254);
BEGIN
    select 'mnemo' into _mnemo;

    --здесь параметр @_data не виден
    insert into table(id, mnemo, data)
    select 1, _mnemo, @_data;
END $$
```

Параметр `@_date` передаётся в скрипт как параметр команды NpgsqlCommand, то есть извне, а его значение используется внутри `DO $$ ... END $$`.

Comment: Вы NpgSQLCommand'у передаёте строку с вашим скриптом и в него хотите вставить _data из c# кода? Я правильно понял?

Comment: Скорректировал вопрос, чтобы понятней было. Мне нужно передавать в скрипт параметр @_data, но в скрипте используются локальные переменные, что приводит к невидимости параметра @_data.